# getURL action script 2 and IE 7/8

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I have several flash movies that need to redirect to an external website at the end of the presentation.  In any browser (firefox, opera, etc.), getURL("http://www.google.com"); works but in IE versions 7 and 8 it just hangs.

I need to use Action Script 2 because I have alot of code that doesn't work in AS 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I haven't touched AS2 in at least a year, but I see to remember this being an issue...

I think it's IE's security settings, are you running this swf locally? You might want to read these:

http://shang-liang.com/blog/issues-with-internet-explorer-7/

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=520661